# PHP List of records from filemaker select button

Tags: php, filemaker

First, thank you for reading this.

I am just starting php and I am tying to make a site using FileMaker to display and enter information.

I have the php connecting to my database, then a search page using a form, then it displays a list of records. I would like to make a "button" that will select one record then display related records.

This is where my trouble is. I do not know how to make a form that will save either the record_Id or key field to then display the next page.

I am using a `foreach` loop to display the list in a table:

```
$records = $result->getRecords();
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Company</th>';
echo '<th>Id Num</th>';
echo '<th>Choose</th>';
echo '</tr>';
foreach ($records as $record) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$record->getField('Company').'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$record->getField('K_Medical').'</td>';
    echo '<td>
    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
#This is where I think I need the button, but instead it just breaks :( 
      <input type="hidden" name="med_id[]" value='$record->getField('K_Medical')/>';
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>';
    echo '</form></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

As you can see I have tried to use a hidden form field to get the key field of the record, but the page dose not work. I get an error 500 when I try to view it in a browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If I have not provided enough information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace :

```
echo '<td>
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
#This is where I think I need the button, but instead it just breaks :( 
  <input type="hidden" name="med_id[]" value='$record->getField('K_Medical')/>';
<input type="submit" />
</form>';
```

By :

```
echo '<td>
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
#This is where I think I need the button, but instead it just breaks :( 
  <input type="hidden" name="med_id[]" value='.$record->getField('K_Medical').'/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>';
```

You have a quotes and concatenation errors.

Comment: Thank you! I replaced the section with:
    echo '<td> <form action="list_clients.php" method="post">' ;
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="med_id" value="'.$record->getField('K_Medical').'" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" />' ;
    echo '</form>';

Well Sorry the formatting on the post is odd. Hopefully you can see this ok. :-)